# Weird contradictory behavior when casting classes in a interface

Tags: java

I encountered some weird behavior in a project I was working on and made this example:

```
class Main implements ClassGetter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.test();
    }

    public void test(){
        consumeClazz(this.getClass()); // error in editor
        consumeClazz((Class<? extends Clazz>) this.getClass()); // error in editor
        consumeClazz(getCastedClass()); // compiles and runs successfully
    }

    public void consumeClazz(Class<? extends Clazz> clazz){
        System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName());
    }
}

interface ClassGetter{
    default Class<? extends Clazz> getCastedClass(){
        return (Class<? extends Clazz>) this.getClass(); // warning in editor
    }
}

class Clazz{}
```

The focus is the `test()` method in the `Main` class and the `getCastedClass()` method of the `ClassGetter` interface. The first two lines in the `test()` method give errors in the editor that explain how `Class<capture of ? extends Main>` cannot be converted to `Class<? extends Clazz>`. However, the last line in `test()` will compile and run successfully, printing out `"Main"`. Interestingly, I get the warning `Unchecked cast: 'Class<capture<? extends ClassGetter>>' to 'Class<? extends Clazz>'` on the line in the `getCastedClass()` method, which made me expect the last example wouldn't work at all like the first two.

Why does the last example work while the first two never compile?

Comment: An instance of Main cannot possibly be an instance of Clazz. An instance of ClassGetter might be an instance of Clazz, if there is a subclass of Clazz that implements ClassGetter. That's why the code in the interface method is legal but unsafe.

Comment: Furthermore, the last one works because we explicitly cast `this.getClass()` (which happens at runtime) and generics are erased, i.e. no longer present at runtime. Basically, we are asking for trouble with this setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why is this illegal in Main?

```
consumeClazz((Class<? extends Clazz>) this.getClass());
```

An instance of Main cannot possibly be an instance of Clazz because they are unrelated classes, and Java does not support multiple inheritance.

---

Why is this legal in ClassGetter?

```
return (Class<? extends Clazz>) this.getClass();
```

An instance of ClassGetter might be an instance of Clazz, if there is a subclass of Clazz that implements ClassGetter. Because it's possible, this is legal but not safe.

---

Why is this legal in Main?

```
consumeClazz(getCastedClass())
```

`getCastedClass()` is declared to return `Class<? extends Clazz>`, which is compatible with the parameter type for `consumeClazz`.

---

Why does it run successfully?

At runtime, the generics are erased, and your `Class<...>` references are just `Class` objects. On that basis, getting the class and printing its name is all legitimate.

Comment: Two follow-up questions: Are all generics erased at runtime, not just those associated with `Class` objects like `List<? extends Clazz>`? Is there anything you can do with the `Class` object that is not legitimate?

Comment: 1. All generic types are erased. 2. If you do something that depends on the particular type, like instantiating it, and it is not the type your code thinks it is, you could get an exception at runtime.